# Coldfusion Builder 3 Coldfusion 11 Display page in Browser

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, localserver, coldfusionbuilder, coldfusion-11

When I go to

> `http://127.0.0.1:8500/index.cfm`

on Chrome, coldfusion throws an error saying that page/path doesn't exists.

How do I see the page on my browser?

Comment: Where did you put your project folder which contains index.cfm page? Make sure it's inside ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot directory.  http://127.0.0.1:8500/projectfoldername/index.cfm try this

Comment: Is the server started? Have you ensured that?

Comment: Thank You! @Ronnie7777, that indeeds works. My problem was that the folder I created was a shortcut and when I would go look in the file explorer, that directory wasn't there, weird. So I created a new folder and cfm file inside, and that one did work. I was able to load it in the browser.

Comment: cool I will post this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure it's inside ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot directory. 127.0.0.1:8500/projectfoldername/index.cfm